# How do I use Playerprefs to save audio settings in the options menu so they load next time the program is run?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started working on a course on Udemy to make a functional menu set for a game I'm working on, and progress came to a crashing halt on the audio settings. The course I'm working on suggested making audio linear on the 20db to -80db scale, which I could tell right away didn't sound right. After some research I found a method to make those settings work properly on a logarithmic scale, and got the audio sounding much more consistent. The problem, however, came after solving that first issue, when I started working on making those settings save so when you exit and re-open the program, the settings would persist where you left them. Every method of saving these settings has been tied to Unity's PlayerPrefs system and I have tried every method I can think of to make it work and I just cannot figure out where I'm going wrong...

The code I'm using is the block below. The way I put the code together is how the tutorial I watched on how to make a logarithmic audio slider had it built to my understanding and comparing. I got a playerprefs editor on the asset store to make it easier to see what was happening and I still can't figure out with that what happened. I'm still pretty new to Unity so any advice or help would be so so very much appreciated!!

[This is the video I watched specifically](https://youtu.be/V_Bf__ynKLE).

This is what my PlayerPrefs are showing.

[image: This is what my PlayerPrefs are showing.]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class OptionsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Toggle fullscreenTog, vsyncTog;

    public ResItem[] resolutions;

    private int selectedResolution;

    public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI resolutionLabel;

    public AudioMixer theMixer;

    public Slider masterSlider, musicSlider, sfxSlider;
    public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI masterLabel, musicLabel, sfxLabel;
    public float masterVolume, musicVolume, sfxVolume;

    public AudioSource sfxLoop;
    
    public 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        fullscreenTog.isOn = Screen.fullScreen;

        if(QualitySettings.vSyncCount == 0)
        {
            vsyncTog.isOn = false;
        }
        else
        {
            vsyncTog.isOn = true;
        }

        //search for resolution in list
        bool foundRes = false;
        
        for(int i=0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            if(Screen.width == resolutions[i].horizontal && Screen.height == resolutions[i].vertical)
            {
                foundRes = true;

                selectedResolution = i;

                UpdateResLabel();
            }
        }

        if (!foundRes)
        {
            resolutionLabel.text = Screen.width.ToString() + " x " + Screen.height.ToString();
        }

        theMixer.SetFloat("MasterVol", Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("MasterVol", 1) * 20));

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
    }

    public void ResLeft()
    {
        selectedResolution--;
        if(selectedResolution < 0)
        {
            selectedResolution = resolutions.Length - 1;
        }

        UpdateResLabel();
    }

    public void ResRight()
    {
        selectedResolution++;
        if(selectedResolution > resolutions.Length - 1)
        {
            selectedResolution = 0;
        }

        UpdateResLabel();
    }

    public void UpdateResLabel()
    {
        resolutionLabel.text = resolutions[selectedResolution].horizontal.ToString() + " x " + resolutions[selectedResolution].vertical.ToString();
    }

    public void ApplyGraphics()
    {
        //apply fullscreen
        //Screen.fullScreen = fullscreenTog.isOn;

        if (vsyncTog.isOn)
        {
            QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
        }

        //set resolution

        Screen.SetResolution(resolutions[selectedResolution].horizontal, resolutions[selectedResolution].vertical, fullscreenTog.isOn);

    }

    public void SetMasterVol(float sliderValue)
    {

        
        //masterLabel.SetText($"{sliderValue:F0)}");

        theMixer.SetFloat("MasterVol", Mathf.Log10(sliderValue) *20);
        
        
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("MasterVol", sliderValue);

        masterLabel.text = (sliderValue * 100).ToString("F0");

        
        
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
       
    }

    public void SetMusicVol()
    {
        musicLabel.text = (musicSlider.value * 100).ToString("F0");

        theMixer.SetFloat("MusicVol", Mathf.Log10(musicSlider.value) *20);

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("MusicVol", musicSlider.value);
    }

    public void SetSFXVol(float sliderValue)
    {
        sfxLabel.text = (sfxSlider.value * 100).ToString("F0");

        theMixer.SetFloat("SFXVol", Mathf.Log10(sliderValue) *20);

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("SFXVol", sliderValue);
    }

    public void PlaySFXLoop()
    {
        sfxLoop.Play(); 
    }

    public void StopSFXLoop()
    {
        sfxLoop.Stop();
    }

    
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ResItem
{
    public int horizontal, vertical;
}
```